# How do I analyze data in a table with multiple subjects?

Tags: r, statistics

I'm trying to get started with R, but are having some issues.
I've got data from a fake race I've invented. It had 4 drivers, where each driver did 3 laps each. The data I've got contains which driver it is, which lap it is, and how quickly he raced that lap. It looks something like this:

```
Driver Lap Time
d1     l1  42
d1     l2  38
d1     l3  37
d2     l1  40
d2     l2  39
etc...
```

**My problem lies in finding a way to create an analysis that checks which lap the drivers did best on.**

My result should say which lap for each individual driver was quickest, and which lap was quickest on average of all drivers.
I have a rough understanding of how I would do this with only one driver, but I've got no clue as to how I can do it with multiple entities. I've tried running a Chi-square test, but that doesn't really work with respect to multiple drivers.

Comment: I'm not sure you need a statistical test to identify the quickest lap of a driver?

Comment: You may need to rephrase your question. To identify the quickest lap of each driver, you could try `group_by(Lap) `, then pick up `min(Time)`. No statistical test is needed. However, if you want to identify the quickest lap of all drivers, you need to compare a summary statistics such as means of different laps of all drivers. You may need some tests here.

Comment: To clarify, and as pointed out by @ZhiqiangWang , my issue is mostly being able to compare the summary of the different drivers.

Answer (score 1):

```
library("tidyverse")


# First, I'll generate a similar dataset.
data <- tibble(
               driver = rep(1:3, each=3),
               lap = rep(1:3, times=3),
               # Generate random integers between 30 and 50 for example time values.
               time = sample(30:50, 9))


# It sounds like there are two questions here:


# Question 1) For each driver, on what lap do they have the lowest time?

min_lap_per_driver <- data %>%
  # Group by driver, because we want to see a value per driver.
  group_by(driver) %>%
  # Then, filter for the row with the minimum time per lap.
  filter(time == min(time))
  # The resulting tibble now describes the lowest lap time for each driver.


# Question 2) What's the average time per lap? Which average is the lowest?

avg_time_per_lap <- data %>%
  # Group by lap (to see on a "per lap" basis)
  group_by(lap) %>%
  # Calculate the average of times per lap.
  summarise(avg_time = mean(time))

lap_with_lowest_time <- avg_time_per_lap %>%
  # Filter for the row with the minimum value of avg_time.
  filter(avg_time == min(avg_time))
  # The resulting tibble describes the lap with the lowest average time.
```

To learn more about creating summary tables, check out [this section of R for Data Science](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html#grouped-summaries-with-summarise). :)